# I just started using Titanium and I can't get the blank apps to open up the iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, titanium

I just started using Titanium (haven't even written any code yet), and I've spent a while trying to get my simulators working. Android seems to work, but I have to try and boot it up 3 times before it actually works (then it is fine). iOS on the other hand just doesn't work.

I'm using Titanium 3.1.3.

I get the following messages in the console:

```
[INFO] :   No module resources to copy
[INFO] :   No CommonJS modules to copy
[INFO] :   Compiling localization files
[INFO] :   Skipping xcodebuild
[INFO] :   Finished building the application in 13s 974ms
[INFO] :   Running application in iOS Simulator
[INFO] :   Launching application in iOS Simulator
[INFO] :   Focusing the iOS Simulator
[INFO] :   Application has exited from iOS Simulator
[INFO] :   Project built successfully in 17s 497ms
```

Apparently there are no errors, but the simulator just doesn't pop up. There are a few lines of code before all this I didn't include, but I don't think those are important. Furthermore, I've looked all over the internet and even Stackoverflow and I can't find a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK do these steps and your app should work

1)Open the simulator manually

2)Click on the reset and Content settings from iOS simulator menu

3)Reset the settings

4)Run the app again and you would be good to go

Thanks

Comment: Nope run it from applications

Comment: I don't think I follow. I'm in my Applications folder. There isn't a simulator in here. Do I look through the xCode packages? Do I look through the Titanium Studio?